# ch2=getchar() doesn't work after last input loop while((ch=getchar())!=EOF)

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    char ch;
    while((ch=getchar())!=EOF){
       putchar(ch);
    }
    char ch2 = 'A';
    printf("ch2=======>%c\n",ch2);
    ch2 = getchar();
    printf("ch2=======>%d\n",ch2);
    return 0;
}
```

I don't understand why it skips the `ch2=getchar()` input, and I get ch2 == -1 which is the value of EOF. I tried to solve this by adding another `getchar()` before `ch2=getchar()`, but I still get ch2 == -1. Why is it and how to fix it? Thanks for helping.

I'm using MacOS.

Comment: Why do you even use EOF in this example? As far as I can see it, this code has nothing to do with a File.

Comment: Last input is `EOF` so it wont go inside the loop;

Comment: Once you've reached the end of input, any further attempt to read will still hit end of input.

Comment: Also, don't store `getchar()`'s return value in a `char`. It returns `int` for a reason.

Comment: @melpomene oh thanks. So does that mean the standard input stream permanently stop as far as I typed EOF?

Comment: @MeikVtune In fact I was trying to store some text input from a while loop, using getchar and a char array and then use `scanf` to read in another input character but I found it skipped, as same as the situation here.

Comment: @TianqingPeng: If you *typed* a Ctrl-Z, then it probably isn't. If you redirected stdin, e.g. with "< somefile.txt", then it is.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, your having a problem with a call to `getchar()`.  I expect that you have read the man page for `getchar()`; But the posted code does not reflect an understanding of what the man page states.  For instance, the returned type from `getchar()` is `int`, NOT `char`.

Answer (score 1):

When compiling, always enable all the warnings, then fix those warnings

I used this version of your code, which cleanly compiles:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    int ch;
    while((ch=getchar())!=EOF){
       putchar(ch);
    }
    int ch2 = 'A';
    printf("ch2=======>%c\n",ch2);
    ch2 = getchar();
    printf("ch2=======>%d\n",ch2);
    return 0;
}
```

then entered:

```
ddd<ctrl-d>ccc<cr>
```

this is the expected (and actual) result:

```
ddd
ddd
ch2=======>A
ccc
ch2=======>99
```

Notes:

1) `getchar()` does not return until a `<cr>` or `<ctrl-d>` is entered

2) all entered characters are echo'd by the terminal driver (not the program)

3) there are still 2 `c`s and a `<cr>` in the input buffer that have not been consumed

Comment: Are you using Linux or MacOS, since I noticed you typed `Ctrl+D`. I copied your code on Mac and run it. It doesn't work. But both my code and yours go on well on Windows.

Comment: I bet he is using Linux.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing surprising. Your loop

```
while((ch=getchar())!=EOF){
       putchar(ch);
}
```

exhausts `stdin` completely. Then `printf()` adds some data to `stdout`, but `stdin` is still empty, so subsequent `getchar()` returns `EOF`.

Comment: Yes, well, but if stdin is input from the keyboard (as usual), even after typing Ctrl-Z, you can usually continue typing, and stdin is not really exhausted.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Time slice between last loop iteration and `ch2 = getchar();` is so small that user surely can't provide new keyboard input and STDIN still may be considered to be empty.

Comment: getchar() is, AFAIK, buffered, so the program will wait for input, until someone presses return (or whatever the key is called). The time slice should be irrelevant.

Comment: OK, I tried in Windows and on the Mac. The Mac doesn't indeed wait and simply returns -1 (EOF) immediately. That matches what you write. But on Windows, getchar() waits until the first `'\n'` is entered. Hmmm... Not consistent. I don't know which is actually correct.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Yes.. I tried on Windows just now and my code works well. It waits for the `getchar()` to input but on Mac it simply returns -1. Lol, I am so confused.